# How to disable loading fonts from fast.fonts.net?

Tags: font, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, loading

I have installed ArcGIS JS API (3.19) locally. But fonts were loaded via Internet.

If I have no Internet connection loading of my app is very slow.

What can I do?
Is it possible to disable loading via Internet?

Comment: A seach on your title tuned up this: http://blog.fonts.com/2015/01/all-the-font-without-the-extra-waiting/  Please be sure to research your topic before posting a question, and to report the result of that research in the question.

Comment: Thanks, @Vince But it is not my question.

Comment: Please **edit** the Question to contain what you do mean, and your research into a solution. I use JS API apps without Internet access all the time.

Comment: @Vince I meant no requests to fast.fonts.net at all.